# Javascript replace on multiple Japanese character

Tags: javascript, jquery, cjk

I want to replace this

> "】|"

character from string with this"】".

> mystring is ="【権利確定月】|1月"

and desired output is

> "【権利確定月】1月".

I have tried with array operation and also with this code:

```
mystring.replace(/】|/g, '】')
```

but not working.

I only want to this with sequence for"】|".
Because after that string will grow like this
example:

> "【権利確定月】1月|other|other|【other】other|other|other".

I have tried many other solution provided on stack overflow but all regex contain single character I want for above sequence character.

Comment: `'【権利確定月】|1月'.replace('】|', '】');`

Comment: this won't replace all occurences, but the first one only

Comment: How about `'【権利確】|】|定月】|1月'.split('】|').join('】');`?

Comment: This also works for me. but not going to fit with other logic.Anyway thank you great logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `|` because it has a special meaning within regex. `】|` equates to `】` or `(an empty string)` so the result is that it replaces `】` with itself and inserts `】` between all the other characters in the string.

```js
var mystring ="【権利確定月】|1月"
var myModifiedString = mystring.replace(/】\|/g, '】');

console.log(myModifiedString);
```

Comment: can u please tell me regex for this sequence"|【"?

Comment: @VivekL `/\|【/g`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the logical OR operator as it is a metacharacter in RegEx.

```js
var x = "【権利確定月】|1月".replace(/】\|/g, '】');
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the strings that need to be replaced in separate variables. Following worked for me.

```
var x = "】|";
var y = "】";
var word = "【権利確定月】|1月";
word.replace(x, y)
```

Comment: This will replace only the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string by `】|` and join by `】`. Or (as was answered before me) escape `|` in regex.

```js
const string = '【権利確】|】|定月】|1月';

let splitAndJoin = string.split('】|').join('】');
let replaceRegex = string.replace(/】\|/g, '】');

console.log(splitAndJoin);
console.log(replaceRegex);
```